# Scheme: Unbound variable: rev

Tags: scheme

I've written the following Scheme code:

```
(define (last-pair list1)
    (if (null? cdr list1)
        car list1
        (last-pair (cdr list1))))

(define (rev list1)
    (if (null? list1)
        list1
        (append (rev (cdr list1)) (list (car list1)))))
```

in a file called test.scm.

At terminal, I run:

load "test.scm"

Then I try:

```
(last-pair (list 1 2 3))

;Value 15: (3)
```

which is correct.

Then I try:

```
(rev (list 1 2 3))

;Unbound variable: rev
;To continue, call RESTART with an option number:
; (RESTART 4) => Specify a value to use instead of rev.
; (RESTART 3) => Define rev to a given value.
; (RESTART 2) => Return to read-eval-print level 2.
; (RESTART 1) => Return to read-eval-print level 1.
```

Seems that it's loading my file properly since it loads `last-pair`, but I'm not sure why I'm getting the above error...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to write

```
(load "test.scm")
```

at the repl. Just `load "test.scm"` probably doesn't load the file.

I think there is a builtin `last-pair` which makes it confusing that your `last-pair` example works and the `rev` one doesn't.